# Ejabberd code import using erlide in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, import, erlang, ejabberd, erlide

trying to understand the working of ejabberd.

I have some problems importing the source code. It would be of great help if you can help trouble shoot.

Following is the problem:

I install eclipse Juno, install erlide from eclipse market place. Set up the installed run-times as per instructions in  [here](http://erlide.org/) .

But when I import the ejabberd source code using the erlang project in import option from the file menu, I get the following error:

An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
java.lang.NullPointerException

In the error log, the last two lines were:

12:15:01,556 F: (CodeManager.java:222) : adding D:/Eclipse_jee_juno/eclipse/plugins/org.erlide.kernel.common_0.15.0.201202052049/ebin to code path for @21690087:: Backend erl5.9.1/956f3_guhanb_53e808_erlide (D:\Erlang_exe\erl5.9.1) R15B01 []

12:15:01,569 F: (ErlConsoleManager.java:39) : console ADDED to Backend erl5.9.1/956f3_guhanb_53e808_erlide (D:\Erlang_exe\erl5.9.1) R15B01 []

which didn't seem much like an error.

-Gb

**The log file as follows:**

```
!SESSION 2012-08-21 16:03:39.552 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1400
java.version=1.6.0_33
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2012-08-21 16:03:44.036
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2012-08-21 16:03:44.036
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for ALT+CTRL+SHIFT+M:
Binding(ALT+CTRL+SHIFT+M,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.pde.ui.openManifest,Open Manifest,
        Open the plug-in manifest,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.navigate,Navigate,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.MakeHandlersGo@7a279c,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(ALT+CTRL+SHIFT+M,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.erlide.ui.open.module,Open Module,
        ,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.navigate,Navigate,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.MakeHandlersGo@1be91c8,
        [Lorg.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.Parameter;@551ee3,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)

!ENTRY org.erlide.core 1 0 2012-08-21 16:03:45.558
!MESSAGE Erlide log is in D:/W2

!ENTRY org.erlide.core 1 0 2012-08-21 16:03:45.584
!MESSAGE *** starting Erlide v0.15.0.201202052049 (core=0.15.0.201202052049) *** (Cp1252) 

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.658
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: Always in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.660
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: Never in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.662
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: Prompt in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.663
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardTransferPage_selectTypes in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.665
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardTransferPage_selectAll in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.667
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardTransferPage_deselectAll in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.668
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardImportPage_browseLabel in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.670
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardImportPage_browse2 in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.672
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardImportPage_selectFolderLabel in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.673
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardImportPage_selectFolderTitle in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.675
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardImportPage_destinationLabel in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.676
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardImportPage_options in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.678
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardImportPage_projectNotExist in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.679
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardImportPage_noOpenProjects in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.681
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardImportPage_undefinedPathVariable in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.683
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardImportPage_containerNotExist in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.684
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardExportPage_errorDialogTitle in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.686
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardExportPage_mustExistMessage in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.687
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardExportPage_mustBeAccessibleMessage in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.689
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardExportPage_detailsMessage in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.691
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardExportPage_whatLabel in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.693
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardExportPage_whereLabel in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.694
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardExportPage_selectionDialogMessage in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.696
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardExportPage_resourceTypeDialog in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.697
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardExportPage_folder in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.699
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardExportPage_browse in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.700
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardExportPage_allTypes in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.702
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardExportPage_specificTypes in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.703
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardExportPage_edit in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.705
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardExportPage_details in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.706
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardExportPage_selectResourcesTitle in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.708
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardExportPage_oneResourceSelected in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.710
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardExportPage_selectResourcesToExport in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.711
!MESSAGE NLS unused message: WizardExportPage_resourceCountMessage in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.713
!MESSAGE NLS missing message: DataTransfer_scanningChildren in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-08-21 16:03:52.715
!MESSAGE NLS missing message: ZipExport_description in: org.erlide.ui.wizards.messages

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2012-08-21 16:04:04.742
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path.<init>(Path.java:153)
    at org.erlide.ui.wizards.ErlangProjectImportWizard.setupDirectoriesPage(ErlangProjectImportWizard.java:92)
    at org.erlide.ui.wizards.ErlangProjectImportWizard$2.pageChanged(ErlangProjectImportWizard.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog$9.run(WizardDialog.java:1553)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.firePageChanged(WizardDialog.java:1551)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.update(WizardDialog.java:1336)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(WizardDialog.java:1264)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.access$4(WizardDialog.java:1238)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog$8.run(WizardDialog.java:1227)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1225)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:915)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$Import.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: I got the source code from here.. [link](http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/)